# Adding an "Android.Views.ViewGroup" to a Xamarin XAML page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need some help with adding an `Android.Views.ViewGroup` to a XAML page.

I have a Xamarin project with a solution structure that looks like this:

- App1

  - /ViewModels

    - /MyPageViewModel.cs
  - /Views

    - /MyPageView.xaml

      - /MyPageView.xaml.cs
- App1.Android

  - /MainActivity.cs
  - /MainApplication.cs
- App1.iOS
- MyAndroidBindingProject

  - /Jars

    - /customViewGroup.aar

Note the `customViewGroup.aar` that I've added to the solution using a Xamarin Android Binding Library.

The AAR file contains an `Android.Views.ViewGroup` class that I'd like to show on `MyPage.xaml` but I have no clue how to do it. I can't seem to find a guide or code sample that fits this exact use case (nor can I find one that involves adding a simple `Android.Views.View` to a Xamarin XAML page).

I've found examples of adding an `Android.Views.ViewGroup` to a native Android application (using Java and XML) but nothing that shows how to add it to a Xamarin XAML page.

Please help!

---

I'm including some source code so you can see what I've tried:

MyPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="App1.Views.MyPage"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModels;"
    xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Com.CustomAAR;assembly=Com.CustomAAR;targetPlatform=Android"
    xmlns:formsAndroid="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ContentView x:Name="contentViewParent">
            <androidWidget:MyCustomViewGroup x:Arguments="{x:Static formsandroid:Forms.Context}"> 
            </androidWidget:MyCustomViewGroup>
        </ContentView>
        <!--<ContentView 
            IsVisible="True"
            IsEnabled="True"
            BindingContext="{Binding MyCustomViewGroup}">
        </ContentView>-->
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    MyCustomViewGroupModel viewModel;

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public MyPage(MyCustomViewGroupModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

#if __ANDROID__
        NativeViewWrapper wrapper = (NativeViewWrapper)contentViewParent.Content;
        MyCustomViewGroup myCustomViewGroup = (MyCustomViewGroup)wrapper.NativeView;

        //myCustomViewGroup = new MyCustomViewGroup(Android.App.Application.Context);

        myCustomViewGroup.SomeAction("");
#endif

        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/xaml/

Comment: Trying that now, thank you!

Comment: Hmmm no dice. I've edited my question to include the code I'm using. The page just appears blank.

Comment: Make sure there's no `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in your `MyPage`.

Comment: Nope there is no attribute on the `MyPage` class

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce your problem on my side, would you mind sharing a basic demo to reproduce this problem?

Comment: check this : https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

Comment: Thank you I will check that out this afternoon! I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include native controls in your Xamarin.Forms page you will need to create a custom control and platform renderer. See the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/) for full walkthrough.

In a gist, you first you declare a new control in your shared project:

```
public class MyCustomViewControl : View
{

}
```

Now in the Android project you create a custom renderer, that will use your custom Android view to display natively:

```
public class MyCustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyCustomViewControl, MyCustomViewGroup>
{
    MyCustomViewGroup viewGroup;

    public MyCustomViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyCustomViewControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            viewGroup= new MyCustomViewGroup(Context);
            SetNativeControl(viewGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

You will also use the renderer to setup events, etc. on the native side.

The renderer is recognized and registered by Xamarin.Forms thanks to the attribute, that can be in the same file as the `Renderer`, above the namespace:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyCustomViewControl), typeof(MyCustomViewRenderer))]
```

Comment: Xamarin.Forms automatically scans the assembly for ExportRenderer attributes to connect renderers with the custom views (I have updated my answer to contain this info, but it is better documented in the link). In the XAML file you put only `<MyCustomViewControl />`

Comment: Put some breakpoints in the Renderer to see if the code is called. If yes, step through to see if especially the `viewGroup= new MyCustomViewGroup(Context);` line does not crash.

Comment: And the `viewGroup` variable is not null and has "data"? Also, does the control have any size? Maybe setting `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` might help

Comment: Otherwise, this technique should work. I have used it several times, exactly as in your case with a native binding library and the component displayed properly. So I really suspect the issue either in the layout, or in the native control itself, the approach should be correct :-)